# why Float.NaN == Float.NaN is false

Tags: java

Why `Float.NaN == Float.NaN` gives `false` ? I have tested it on more than one JVMs.

Any help is appreciated .

```
  System.out.println(Float.NaN == Float.NaN); // gives false
```

Comment: But haven't googled it enough...

Comment: Find the reason [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341653/float-nan-float-nan)

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm thinking `NaN` is specified to be unequal to any other number. (Or, in fact, *uncomparable*, but `==` can't express that.)

Answer (score 3):

That's not specific to Java.

IEEE754's [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) are by contract equal to no number, even themselves.

Comment: isn't that the easiest way to detect NaN - if the number is not itself?

Comment: @TobiasLangner As put by Wikipedia : *"The equality and inequality predicates are non-signaling so x = x returning false can be used to test if x is a quiet NaN"*. But in your code the clearest would be to use `Float.isNaN`.