# Why can't we use '==' to compare two float or double numbers

Tags: java, floating-point, double, equals

I am reading Effective java by Joshua Bloch and in **Item 8: Obey the general contract when overriding equals**, this statement is written

> for float fields, use the Float.compare method; and for double fields, use
>   Double.compare. The special treatment of float and double fields is made
>   necessary by the existence of Float.NaN, -0.0f and the analogous double
>   constants;

Can someone explain me with example why we can't use `==` for float or double comparison

Comment: Is a NaN equal to any other NaN?  Is it greater than, less than or equal to any other number?  Is -0.0f equal to 0.0f?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9341669/1276341

Comment: It depends on what you want to do.  IIRC (don't hold me to this) `NaN == NaN` is false, eg.  But the official spec of `compare` doesn't give you much info on how the "oddball" cases are handled.  More important is to remember to never compare for "equal" at all, except in special cases where you know what you're doing.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819738/why-does-double-nan-double-nan-return-false

Comment: @devnull Your duplicate suggestion is TERRIBLE. This question is about why `==` is not enough like an equivalence relation, and `Float.compare(x,y)==0` is better because it is an equivalence relation. The accepted answer in the question you suggest is about building an “up-to-epsilon” equality that is EVEN LESS OF AN EQUIVALENCE RELATION. Please read floating-point questions carefully  before suggesting that comparing up to epsilon is the answer or that it is a duplicate of a question about comparing up to epsilon.

Comment: @PascalCuoq The answer <http://stackoverflow.com/a/3833200/2235132> that is *not* accepted is the one I was referring to.

Comment: Somebody ought to have added an example two floats like `20000000` and `20000001` wouldn't be equal if compared using `==`!

Answer (score 20):

From apidoc, [`Float.compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare%28float,%20float%29):

> Compares the two specified float values. The sign of the integer value returned is the same as that of the integer that would be returned by the call:
>
> new Float(f1).compareTo(new Float(f2))

[`Float.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Float%29):

> Compares two Float objects numerically. There are two ways in which comparisons performed by this method differ from those performed by the Java language numerical comparison operators (<, <=, ==, >= >) when applied to primitive float values:
>
> - Float.NaN is considered by this method to be equal to itself and greater than all other float values (including Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY).
> - 0.0f is considered by this method to be greater than -0.0f.
>
> **This ensures that the natural ordering of Float objects imposed by this method is consistent with equals.**

Consider the following code:

```
    System.out.println(-0.0f == 0.0f); //true
    System.out.println(Float.compare(-0.0f, 0.0f) == 0 ? true : false); //false      
    System.out.println(Float.NaN == Float.NaN);//false
    System.out.println(Float.compare(Float.NaN, Float.NaN) == 0 ? true : false); //true
    System.out.println(-0.0d == 0.0d); //true
    System.out.println(Double.compare(-0.0d, 0.0d) == 0 ? true : false);//false     
    System.out.println(Double.NaN == Double.NaN);//false
    System.out.println(Double.compare(Double.NaN, Double.NaN) == 0 ? true : false);//true
```

The ouput is not correct, since something that is not a number, is simply not a number, and should be treated as equal from number comparison point of view. It is also clear that `0=-0`.

Let's see what [`Float.compare`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Float.java#Float.compare%28float%2Cfloat%29) does:

```
public static int compare(float f1, float f2) {
   if (f1 < f2)
        return -1;           // Neither val is NaN, thisVal is smaller
    if (f1 > f2)
        return 1;            // Neither val is NaN, thisVal is larger

    int thisBits = Float.floatToIntBits(f1);
    int anotherBits = Float.floatToIntBits(f2);

    return (thisBits == anotherBits ?  0 : // Values are equal
            (thisBits < anotherBits ? -1 : // (-0.0, 0.0) or (!NaN, NaN)
             1));                          // (0.0, -0.0) or (NaN, !NaN)
}
```

[`Float.floatToIntBits`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits%28float%29):

> Returns a representation of the specified floating-point value according to the **IEEE 754 floating-point "single format" bit layout.**
>   Bit 31 (the bit that is selected by the mask 0x80000000) represents the sign of the floating-point number. Bits 30-23 (the bits that are selected by the mask 0x7f800000) represent the exponent. Bits 22-0 (the bits that are selected by the mask 0x007fffff) represent the significand (sometimes called the mantissa) of the floating-point number.
>
> If the argument is positive infinity, the result is 0x7f800000.
>
> If the argument is negative infinity, the result is 0xff800000.
>
> If the argument is NaN, the result is 0x7fc00000.
>
> In all cases, the result is an integer that, when given to the intBitsToFloat(int) method, will produce a floating-point value the same as the argument to floatToIntBits (**except all NaN values are collapsed to a single "canonical" NaN value**).

From [JLS 15.20.1. Numerical Comparison Operators <, <=, >, and >=](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1)

> The result of a floating-point comparison, as determined by the specification of the IEEE 754 standard, is:
>
> - If either operand is NaN, then the result is false.
> - All values other than NaN are ordered, with negative infinity less than all finite values, and positive infinity greater than all finite values.
> - Positive zero and negative zero are considered equal. For example, -0.0<0.0 is false, but -0.0<=0.0 is true.
> - Note, however, that the methods Math.min and Math.max treat negative zero as being strictly smaller than positive zero.

For strict comparisons where operands are positive zero and negative zero the result will be wrong.

From [JLS 15.21.1. Numerical Equality Operators == and !=](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1):

> The result of a floating-point comparison, as determined by the specification of the IEEE 754 standard, is:
>
> Floating-point equality testing is performed in accordance with the rules of the IEEE 754 standard:
>
> - If either operand is NaN, then the result of == is false but the result of != is true. Indeed, the test x!=x is true if and only if the value of x is NaN. The methods Float.isNaN and Double.isNaN may also be used to test whether a value is NaN.
> - Positive zero and negative zero are considered equal. For example, -0.0==0.0 is true.
> - Otherwise, two distinct floating-point values are considered unequal by the equality operators. In particular, there is one value representing positive infinity and one value representing negative infinity; each compares equal only to itself, and each compares unequal to all other values.

For equality comparisons where both operands are [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) the result will be wrong.

Since [total ordering (`=`, `<`, `>`,`<=`, `>=`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) is used by many important algorithms (see [all the classes that implement the Comparable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)) it is better to use the compare method because it will yield more consistent behavior.

The consequence of the [total ordering in the context of the IEEE-754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Total-ordering_predicate) is the difference between the positive and negative zero.

For instance,  if you use the equality operator instead of the compare method, and have some collection of values and your code logic makes some decisions based on the ordering of the elements, and you somehow start getting a surplus of NaN values they'll all be treated as different values instead as the same values.

That may likely produce error in the behavior of the program proportional to the amount/rate of NaN values. And if you have a lot of positive and negative zeroes, that's just one pair to affect your logic with error.

Float [uses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) IEEE-754 32 bit format and Double [uses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) IEEE-754 64 bit format.

Answer (score 8):

`float` (and `double`) have some special bit sequences that are reserved for special meanings that are not "numbers":

- Negative infinity, internal representation `0xff800000`
- Positive infinity, internal representation `0x7f800000`
- Not a Number, internal representation `0x7fc00000`

Each of these returns `0` (meaning they are "the same") when compared to itself using `Float.compare()`, but the following comparisons using `==` differ from this for  `Float.NaN`:

```
Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY == Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY // true
Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY == Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY // true
Float.NaN == Float.NaN // false
```

So when comparing `float` values, to be consistent for all values, including the special `Float.NaN` value, `Float.compare()` is the best option.

The same applies to `double`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `Float.compare()` returns an `int`, not "false" (or "true"). All following calls to `Float.compare()` return `0`: `Float.compare(Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY,Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY)`, `Float.compare(Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)`, `Float.compare(Float.NaN,Float.NaN)`. I am sure of this because I just executed it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK - I've edited the answer to explain what zero means (even though it's in the javadoc of `compare()`)

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons to compare floating-point objects:

- I am doing math, so I want to compare their numerical values. Numerically, –0 equals +0, and a NaN is not equal to anything, not even itself, because “equal” is a property that only numbers have, and NaN is not a number.
- I am working with objects in a computer, so I need to distinguish different objects and place them in order. This is necessary for sorting objects in a tree or other container, for example.

The `==` operator provides mathematical comparisons. It returns false for `NaN == NaN` and true for `-0.f == +0.f`

The `compare` and `compareTo` routines provide object comparisons. When comparing a NaN to itself, they indicate that it is the same (by returning zero). When comparing `-0.f` to `+0.f`, they indicate they are different (by returning non-zero).