# Checking if a number entered has an integer value

Tags: c#

First of all I am a beginner in C#, I have just started to play around with it as that's what my University course requires.

My problem is an assignment question which says:

h)  To test if a number entered has an integer value. Hint: The number will have to be of type Double. If, for example, the number is 2.5 that doesn’t have an integer value but 2 does. You will need to use  Convert.ToInt32(TheNumber) to convert the Double to an Int then compare the two.

```
double a, b, result;
            Console.WriteLine("Input a number");
            a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            b = Convert.ToInt32(a);
```

This is what I have at the moment and I don't know how to compare these 2 to test which one is an integer. I am pretty sure that you have to use an if statement but how to tell C# to test which of these 2 numbers is an integer and which one isn't!

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: have you tried `a == b` - https://dotnetfiddle.net/6A3GwH?

Comment: This is saying that if a is equal to b but they will never be equal as one number will be a decimal and another number a whole number which is a integer. I would need something like if I enter a = 2.5 it will say 2.5 is not an integer but then b = convert it to integer and print that 2 is an integer

Comment: `double a, b` - where is the integer? `2.00000` is the same as `2` as the fiddle shows (and everybody knows)

Comment: The next line ask user to input a number and that is stored in a, and b basically converts a to integer

Comment: 1. Enter `string`; 2. Check it with `decimal.TryParse`; 3. If (2) is `false` then `Int32.TryParse`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

I'd do it like this:

```
double d;
int i;
Console.WriteLine("Input a number");
d = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
i = Convert.ToInt32(d);
if(i == d) Console.WriteLine("It is an integral value");
```

This means: if you convert a double to an integer, it will lose all its digits after the decimal point. If this integer has the same value as the double, then the double had no digits after the decimal point, so it has an integer value.

Comment: It's giving me an error message with line                                                            d = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())                                                            and I don't know why really

Comment: What is the error? It looks like the assignment lets you assume that the user enters an actual number, such as `2`, rather than something invalid like `gfjhsgfd`.

Comment: when I input 2.5 for example i get An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: how would I for example declare variable b to be any number from 1 to 100 (only whole numbers) and then if a is not equal to any of these numbers then round it up to nearest whole number maybe?

Comment: `If( i == d )` will not work, because it will implicitly convert i to double and then perform equality comparison between doubles, which **does not work**. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17898266/773113

Comment: @Mike Nakis Did you try it? It will work nicely in this case (small integers)

Comment: Hmm, yes, it works, the way I was thinking about it was flawed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `TryParse` method which returns boolean

```
        double mydouble;
        int myInt;
        string value = Console.ReadLine();
        if (double.TryParse(value, out mydouble))
        {
            //This is double value, you can perform your operations here
        }
        if (int.TryParse(value, out myInt))
        {
            //This is Int value, you can perform your operation here
        }
```

Comment: It would be better, if you provide OP with sample code.

Comment: I was writing , btw what is OP?

Comment: OP = Original Poster.

Comment: You can look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean).
**The characters "OP" stand for "Original Poster", the person originally asking the question.**

Comment: Haseeb, this will not work exactly as presented. `double.TryParse()` will succeed both for real and integer numbers, so the part where you say "//This is double value, you can perform your operations here" will execute always, both for real and for integer numbers, not only for real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this:

```
double d;
int i;      
Console.WriteLine("Input a number");
d = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
i = Convert.ToInt32(d);
if(i == d) Console.WriteLine("It is an integral value");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `TryParse` with do while loop

```
int  number;
string value;
do
{
  Console.Write("Enter a number : ");
  value =Console.ReadLine();

  if (!Int32.TryParse(value, out number))
       {
         Console.WriteLine("Wrong Input!!!!");
       }

}while (!Int32.TryParse(value, out number));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use '%' operator.

```
double number = 3.1;
bool isInteger = (number % 1) == 0;
string result = isInteger ? "" : "NOT ";
Console.WriteLine($"Number '{number}' is {result}integer.");
```