# Class equals method is confusing

Tags: java, equals

I'm studying object oriented programming in Java at my school and I had to do an exercise to compare Circles.

I had the Circle Class with these

> private int id;
>
> private String bgColor;
>
> private String fgColor;

And inside it I had to use the equals method to compare two circles (by using these three attributes): **a circle is equal to other circle if its radius and the bg and fgColor are the same.**

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    boolean found;
    if (obj == null) {
        found = false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        found = false;
    }
    final Circle other = (Circle) obj;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.radius) == Double.doubleToLongBits(other.radius)) {
        //found = false;
        
        if (Objects.equals(this.bgColor, other.bgColor)) {
            //found = false;
            
            if (Objects.equals(this.fgColor, other.fgColor)) {
                return true;
            }//end if fgColor
            else{
                found = false;
            }   
        }//end if bgcolor
        else{
            found = false;
        }   
    }//end if radius
    else{
        found = false;
    }   

    return found;
}
```

But my teacher told me that the code above is "confusing", but I don't understand why.

Do you know a better solution?

My teacher wants that we folow this structure (this case is only comparing one property):

```
public boolean equals (Object obj)
{
      boolean b;

      if(obj == null)
      {
              b = false;
      }
      else
      {
              if(this == obj)//same object
              {
                      b = true;
              }
              else
              {
                      if(obj instanceof Book)                   
                      {
                              Book other = (Book) obj; 
                              b = (this.id == other.id); 
                      } 
                      else
                      {
                              b = false;
                      }
              }
      }

      return b;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is. Very confusing.

Comment: @Tiny That would be about as confusing as his code above.

Comment: Instead of having separate `else` and `ifs`, use the `else if` construct. There's no advantage in having so many braces.

Comment: Am I the only one who dislikes "one return" per method in Java in 2015? For me it worsens the readability a lot, won't approve such a code at code-review without a good reason. (I am speaking of teacher's code)

Comment: I'm confused by `Double.doubleToLongBits`... Is there not `Double.equals`? Why couldn't you use `==` there? Same for the color strings. `bgColor.equals(other.bgColor)` is the correct way

Comment: @Tiny The OP explicitly states two objects are equal if the radius, bgColor and fgColor are equal

Comment: @Tiny: quoting directly from the OP - "A circle is equals to other circle if its radius and the bg and fgColor are the same".  The code you're referring to is an _example_ their teacher has provided

Comment: @Tiny - are you actually being serious? The OP needs to compare their Circle class for equality and the Book class is provided as an _example_ of structure - the key part being structure

Comment: Downvoting and flagging, this question should be posted on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and not here.

Comment: @user3707125 yes, returning early also simplifies conditionals (no need for `else`)

Answer (score 3):

This is about the most concise version (assuming that radius and colors can't be null). The null check for obj is taken care of by the instanceof test:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

   if( ! (obj instanceof Circle ) )
       return false;

    Circle rhs = (Circle)obj;
    return Double.compare( radius, rhs.radius ) == 0 &&
        bgColor.equals( rhs.bgColor ) &&
        fgColor.equals( rhs.fgColor );
}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted the original version of this from a couple of minutes ago: that was a slip of the `enter' key. I have every reason to believe this correct. Please be kind enough to see if you still think this deserves a downvote (and kindly say why).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898266/why-cant-we-use-to-compare-two-float-or-double-numbers

Comment: This won't compile. There is no variable "other". The parm is called obj.

Comment: Also you fail to check for null. You will get an NPE if obj is null.

Comment: @bhspencer 
instanceof takes care of the need to check obj for null. See "Effective Java" (or the spec).

Comment: @bhspencer Double comparison now ammended according to your link. Thanks.

Comment: I did the original downvote due to what appeared to be a blatant c+p from a deleted answer.  It still stands as your code has other issues; most notable allowing subclasses and potential NPEs

Comment: @MrWiggles - NPEs are catered for in the comments: no sensible implementor of Circle would allow a constructor with null values for the colors. 

What do you mean by `allowing subclasses'? The instanceof check is correct (and indeed the idiomatic way of implementing equals) - it's basically equivalent to the if( getClass().equals ...) of other answers.

Comment: `instanceof` is idiomatic for final classes/equals methods, but violates the equality contract otherwise.  Without further clarification about whether the `bgColor` and fgColor` are mandatory you shouldn't make that assumption.

Comment: I agree with @MrWiggles here, you cannot assume that the color strings are never null unless that is stipulated in the spec.

Comment: @MrWiggles - Strictly, you are correct about inheritance. However, catering for that correct requires more than just the getClass check in general: https://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html, so I figured that (given the OP's level of Java knowledge) that the simplified version I posted was more appropriate.

Comment: Also I think your earlier use of == was ok in this particular instance and the use of Double.compare is unnecessary (possibly even undesirable). Check the API doc on the differences between Double.compare and ==.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a IDE (I hope you do) probably it has an option to generate code for equals method.
Eclipse generates something like:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Circle other = (Circle) obj;
    if (bgColor == null) {
        if (other.bgColor != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!bgColor.equals(other.bgColor))
        return false;
    if (fgColor == null) {
        if (other.fgColor != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!fgColor.equals(other.fgColor))
        return false;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(radius) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.radius))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

And don't forget implements hashcode method when you implements equals method and vicecersa.

Comment: The spec does not call for comparing IDs "A circle is equals to other circle if its radius and the bg and fgColor are the same."

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a single return statement consider using multiple return points to simplify the code. This way you do not need extra boolean variables to hold on to the results of prior conditions.

```
public class Circle {
    public double radius;
    public String bgColor;
    public String fgColor;

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (obj instanceof Circle) {
            Circle other = (Circle) obj;
            if (Double.compare(this.radius, other.redius) == 0 
                    && compareStrings(this.fgColor, other.fgColor)
                    && compareStrings(this.bgColor, other.bgColor)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean compareStrings(String a, String b) {
        if (a == null && b == null) {
            return true;
        } else if (a != null) {
            return a.equals(b); 
        } else if (b != null) {
            return b.equals(a);
        }
        return false;
    }   
}
```

This solution allows for the possibility that either of the String fgColor or bgColor might be null without throwing a NPE. The String comparison has been extracted into its own function to aid readability and reduce confusion.

Comment: If `fgColor` or `bgColor` are null your code will throw a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Fixed to avoid possible NPE if color strings are null.

Comment: The instance of test caters for null, so the initial test is redundant.

Comment: if (Double.compare(this.radius, other.redius) == 0 
                    && compareStrings(this.fgColor, other.fgColor)
                    && compareStrings(this.bgColor, other.bgColor)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

can be reduced to:
return Double.compare(this.radius, other.redius) == 0 
                    && compareStrings(this.fgColor, other.fgColor)
                    && compareStrings(this.bgColor, other.bgColor);

Comment: @user217281728 reducing the number of lines taken up by a piece of code is not always desirable, sometimes the more compact code is less readable. I would argue that evaluating a condition that contains 3 function calls and 3 boolean operators in the same statement as the return does not enhance readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        // its a Circle so its safe to case
        Circle other = (Circle)obj;

        // equals ONLY if 3 conditions are met
        if (radius == other.getRadius() &&
            bgColor.equals(other.getBgColor()) &&
            fgColor.equals(other.getFgColor())){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This will throw an NPE if bgColor is null. Also consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898266/why-cant-we-use-to-compare-two-float-or-double-numbers

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to my previous answer:

Writing an equals method that works correctly in the presence of subclassing is extremely non-trivial (see Joshua Bloch's comments in Item 8 of `Effective Java').

Indeed, until relatively recently the was no widely known single method for doing this.

In 2009, the article ["How to Write an Equality Method in Java"](https://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html)
by Martin Odersky, Lex Spoon, and Bill Venners shows that this can be achieved in terms of a `canEqual' method.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @bhspencer It seems a bit lengthy for that. Also, the comments under my previous answer were getting to the 'recommended you continue in chat' length.

Comment: This should be edited into your original answer, since this answer does not provide an answer to the question on its own.