# incomparable types: boolean and double

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class quadrado {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int xp1,xp2,xp3,xp4,yp1,yp2,yp3,yp4;
        double c1,c2,c3;
        Scanner aa = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.print("Insira a abcissa do P1\n");
            xp1 = aa.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Insira a ordenada do P1\n");
            yp1 = aa.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Insira a abcissa do P2\n");
            xp2 = aa.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Insira a ordenada do P2\n");
            yp2 = aa.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Insira a abcissa do P3\n");
            xp3 = aa.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Insira a ordenada do P3\n");
            yp3 = aa.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Insira a abcissa do P4\n");
            xp4 = aa.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Insira a ordenada do P4\n");
            yp4 = aa.nextInt();

            c1= Math.sqrt((xp2-xp1)^2 + (yp2-yp1)^2);
            c2= Math.sqrt((xp3-xp2)^2 + (yp3-yp2)^2);
            c3= Math.sqrt((xp4-xp3)^2 + (yp4-yp3)^2);

            System.out.print("A figura é um quadrado: "+c1);

            if (c1==c2==c3) {                                           // sendo os lados consecutivos
                System.out.print("A figura é um quadrado"); }
            else {
                System.out.print("A figura não é um quadrado"); }


        }
    }
```

I'm trying to write something that given the coordinates of 4 points decides if it forms a square. I  decided to get the lenght of 3 vectors and, iff they are all the same size, it says it is a square. I'm a beginner so i really need help :/

Answer (score 4):

```
if (c1==c2==c3)
```

Lets break this down:

```
c1==c2
```

This is either `true` or `false`, lets call this `b1`.

```
b1 == c3
```

`b1` is a `boolean`, `c3` is still a `double` - error

Also, [`==` can cause problems with `double`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898266/why-cant-we-use-to-compare-two-float-or-double-numbers). Although it's use should be fine here, and in the majority of places, it's something to bear in mind.

Comment: double `==` can be a problem, except in cases like this where it would be just fine.

Comment: @PeterLawrey best to breed good habits early, no? I have reworded a bit.

Comment: I agree you should always consider it, and only not do it if you are confident it's not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write `c1==c2==c3` as this means `(c1==c2)==c3` so if c1 == c2 you are saying `true == c3` which doesn't make sense.

Most likely you intended

```
if (c1 == c2 && c2 == c3)
```

Note: while `double` can have representation error, in this case that error would be consistent and you don't need to check for a small calculation error.

Conversely if you have non integers which have been calculated via a different means, you need to allow for some error (or use rounding)

```
 double a = input();
 double b = input();
 double c = input();

 if (a == b && b == c) // ok
 if (a + b == c) // not ok, needs rounding or tolerance.
```

You should also note that `^` mean bitwise XOR, not power of.  You can instead do

```
 double c1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xp2-xp1, 2) + Math.pow(yp2-yp1, 2));
```

Comment: Could you explain why the error should be consistent in this case?

Comment: If you do `Math.sqrt(N)` where `N` is an integer, you always get the same value.

Comment: @FrankPuffer similarly, `Math.pow(N, 2)` always gives the same result for `N`  It's important to remember that representation errors are not random errors (at least not in Java)

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice that the input values are integers. Still, if someone later decides to use non-integer inputs which is not too unlikely, it won't work anymore.

Comment: Having looked at this further, I agree with Peter.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing doubles, you should always allow a small tolerance because you usually get roundoff errors:

```
static final double TOL = 1.0e-8;
if (Math.abs(c1-c2) < TOL && Math.abs(c1-c3) < TOL) ...
```

By the way, it is not sufficient to check if all sides have equal lengths because this is also the case for a diamond shape. You also need to check for right angles.

Comment: Although in this case the errors would always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write if c1==c2 && c2 ==c3 instead.

Your compiler is complaining since c1==c2==c3  is evaluated as (c1==c2)==c3 and this is not allowed in java since the c1==c2 is a boolean type.

Note that due to imprecision in floating point, it would be better if you compared for equality before taking the square roots as those types are integers. That said, it doesn't actually matter in this case since the computed lengths are not combined in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare more than two things like that.
Java is comparing c1 & c2, then it is comparing the result of c1 & c2 with c3. 
If you want to compare multiple variables you need to do it with more if statements.

```
if (c1 == c2 && c1 == c3 && c2 == c3) {...}
```

You can also do it with a method like that:

```
public boolean allSame(Object... os) {
     Object first = os[0];

     for (Object o : os) 
         if (!first.equals(os)) return false;

     return true;
}
```

Comment: Comparing `c2 == c3` should always be redundant. for example see your second method which doesn't do this (though it compares the first element to itself)

Comment: I'm interested in what you say here Peter. If you have time, might you be able to expand on this? My instinct is not to compute the unnecessary square roots.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Except that in his second method it actually is necessary to compare `c2` and `c3`, because while `==` is guaranteed to be transitive, `.Equals` is not.

Comment: @Bathsheba You don't need to compute any `sqrt` here. If `a == b` then `sqrt(a) == sqrt(b)`  In this case, the converse happens to be true as the inputs are integers.