# Exponentional function parameters

Tags: java, math, regression, exponential

I have 3 points `[x0 y0]`, `[x1 y1]`, `[x2 y2]`  with strict conditional `x0<x1<x2`, `y0<y1<y2`. All this points lay on some exponentional functions `y=ae^(bx)+c`. I need to find `a,b,c`... It's not possible to solve system of 3 equations precisely, therefore I need to approximate it. Is there some math library in java that will help me solve this problem? I find something similar on mathcad

https://help.ptc.com/mathcad/en/index.html#page/PTC_Mathcad_Help/exponential_regression.html but not find in java.

Other way - how to solve system of 3 equations and 3 values approximately.

`ae^(bx_0)+c=y_0
 ae^(bx_1)+c=y_1
 ae^(bx_2)+c=y_2`

Comment: Would you please post the three data points?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559140/having-trouble-solving-cubic-equations-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve a system of non-linear equations, for which only an approximate solution is possible but can be done using the **Newton Raphson's Multivariate method**.

The algorithm is, quite frankly, a notational pain but you can go through it here - 
http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e176/lectures/NM/node21.html.
What is happening essentially is you have a function whose derivative lead you to an 'equilibrium' from an initial random point (which you guess as a possible root)

If you are not willing to write the code yourself this repo can give you a starter of sorts - https://github.com/prasser/newtonraphson. 
But AFAIK, no ready library exists for this purpose. You can use Wolfram's Mathematica or MATLAB/OCTAVE for ready libraries though.

That said, here are a few other (more complicated) things you can look into

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm
2. https://www1.fpl.fs.fed.us/optimization.html
3. http://icl.cs.utk.edu/f2j/
4. http://optalgtoolkit.sourceforge.net/
5. http://scribblethink.org/Computer/Javanumeric/index.html
6. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html

Hope this helps!