# How to display NaN in Java?

Tags: java, math, nan, arithmetic-expressions

In Java, I am dividing by zero, which obviously does not produce a number.

```
public class tempmain {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        float a=3/0;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be "NaN", but it shows the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at tempmain.main(tempmain.java:6)
```

Is there any way (apart from `if(denominator==0)`) by which NaN can be displayed?

Comment: Try `3/0.0`. When you write `something/0`, you'll get `ArithmeticException` anyway. You can get `NaN` jnly when you work with doubles.

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618059/in-java-what-does-nan-mean

Comment: @JRichardSnape that gives "Infinity" not "NaN"

Comment: If you setup the `float` properly (without using integers), you can simple do: `Float.isNaN(a)` and it will tell you if there is a NaN or not

Comment: See also [Alnitak's answer to the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12954430/13531).

Comment: Catch the exception and print "NaN"!

Comment: Not marked as a duplicate anymore :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting the unexpected ArithmeticException because of the way that your numeric literals 3 and 0 are treated.  They are interpreted as integers, despite the fact that you assign `a` to be a float.  Java will interpret `3` as an integer, `3f` as a float and `3.0` or `3d` as a double.  The division is performed as integer division and the result cast to a float.  To see another interesting other effect of this - try `float a = 1/3` and inspect `a` - you will find it is 0.0, rather than 0.3333.... as you might expect.

To get rid of the Exception - change

```
float a = 3/0;
```

for

```
float a = 3f/0;
```

As others have noted in comments and answers, if you then print `a`, you will see `Infinity` rather than `NaN`.  If you really want to print NaN in this case, you can test a for being infinite i.e.

```
if (Float.isInfinite(a)) {
     System.out.println("I want to print Infinity as NaN");
}
```

but I'd recommend against it as highly misleading - but I suspect that's not what you meant anyway

Answer (score 4):

First, dividing by zero in floating point numbers does not give NaN, it gives infinity. Second, you're dividing integers, not floats.

```
float a = 3.0f/0.0f;
System.out.println(a);  // Prints Infinity
```

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
public class tempmain {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    try {
       float a=3/0;
       System.out.println(a);
    } catch (ArithmeticException x) {
       System.out.println("Not Evaluable");
    }
}

}
```

There is also this option:

```
{
...
//if (a != a) {        // these two are equivalent
if (Float.isNaN(a)) {
  System.out.println("NaN");
  }
}
```

See: [Float.NaN == Float.NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341653/float-nan-float-nan)

Comment: You can do that comparison, but it is very inefficient. Better of using `Float.isNaN()` or `Double.isNaN()`

Comment: @Ascalonian Why should that be inefficient? this is the code of isNaN: `public static boolean isNaN(float f) {
 return f != f;
}`

Comment: @Absurd-Mind good find. I was just told before not to use it. I guess I should have checked myself to confirm. Thanks for figuring that out!

Comment: The reason why you should use `isNaN()` instead of `a != a`, is that the former is explicit and can also be understood by someone not aware of the `NaN != NaN` concept.

Comment: I totally agree with you.